# Create query snapshot to listen live changes

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I created a function which gets data from Firestore using if condition. I have achieved it with `.get()` method but it does not get updated in real time, I mean if any record is updated in the server, it doesn't reflect here.

Here is my function

```
   async getMyPosts() {
    this.query = firebase.firestore().collection('complaints')
    if (this.complaint_status_filter_active==true) {  // you decide
      this.query = this.query
      .where('complaint_status', '==', this.complaint_status_filter_value)
      .limit(5)
    }
    const questions = await this.query.get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          console.log(doc.data())
        })
      })
      .catch(catchError)
  }
```

What should be used instead of `get()` to have real time update

### Edit 1

In below example I am able to use snapshot changes using Angular Firestore but here I am not able to use `if` condition

How do I add where condition with if clause here? Code:

```
  this.firestore.collection('complaints' , ref => ref
.where('complaint_status', '==', this.complaint_status_filter_value)
.limit(5)
.orderBy("complaint_date","desc") 
)
.snapshotChanges()
.subscribe(response => {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [onSnapshot()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#onsnapshot) to get realtime updates, as illustrated in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen).

```
this.query.onSnapshot(doc => {
    // ...
})
```

Comment: seen the document, in example documentation they used this on a doc, can you help me where in my case i use this ?

Comment: i have updated my question, in edit 1 , i am able to use onsnapshot changes but cant use if there, please help if possible

Comment: how do i use this without a doc ?  `db.collection("cities").doc("SF")
    .onSnapshot(function(doc) {
        console.log("Current data: ", doc.data());
    });`  , if i remove doc it gives error

Comment: If you are trying to query a collection and get realtime results, then you should follow the documentation for that. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection